# Are there any adapters for ribbon cable to HDMI?

Tags: hdmi, television, smart-device, hdtv

I have a JVC - LT-40CA790 Android TV 40" Smart Full HD LED TV with Google Assistant. Which has a broken screen but everything else seems to work I think like the audio, not sure bout the rest.

I took it apart and managed to safely remove all the parts and I was wondering if it was possible to make like a Smart box and connect it to another TV.

I noticed it had a ribbon cable which I assume connects the video feed. Is there any component out there that can convert the ribbon feed to something else like HDMI?

Or do you guys have another project idea I could do with these parts? I could sell them for parts, but I think it’d be more fun to repurpose it and try to learn a thing or two. I’ve got basic arduino knowledge but nothing major electrical.

Thanks guys, appreciate any and all help.

Here’s an overview of all the parts.
[image: overview of the TV]

Overview 2
[image: another overview]

Here’s the power supply board I think? The power cable was connected to this
[image: power supply board]

I think this is the motherboard or main logic area?
[image: motherboard?]

This is the ribbon cable I want to try to find an output hdmi connector for to connect to another TV.
[image: ribbon cable]

Answer (score 0):

Those cables are mostly non-standard and hard to replace, let alone transform to hdmi. I would reccomend getting a different "smart tv" or see if this is covered under your tv warrenty.